# UIImagePickerController takePicture fails to show shutter animation

Tags: ios

I am using a standard UIImagePickerController with my own overlayView and am taking a picture using the `takePicture` method. The problem is that the shutter animation isn't happening. Does it need to be triggered manually? This is on iOS 6.